# atk4 SQLAuth in Frontend.php

Tags: atk4

in Frontend.php I replaced this:

```
$this->add('BasicAuth')
        ->allow('demo','demo')
        // use check() and allowPage for white-list based auth checking
        //->check()
        ;
```

With this:

```
$this->add('SQLAuth')->setSource('user','email','password')
// use check() and allowPage for white-list based auth checking
//->check()
;
```

based on this you tube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_OROS53Fq8&feature=relmfu

However, the SQLAuth will not work.  I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function loaded() on a non-object in
C:\wamp\www\atk4\lib\Auth\Basic.php on line 242
```

My table name is correct, and i know the connection is working and there are users in the table, because I built a user registration form and CRUD that works as I walked through the you tube video.

Anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: anybody have any idea what's going on?  i don't even know what that error means..  anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAuth is going to be removed in 4.2 and should not be used anymore.  You can use BasicAuth and set it to respond to a model based on your user table